# AppHarbor: NancyFx app got Internal Server Error

Tags: mysql, deployment, frameworks, appharbor, nancy

I've recently deployed to http://domainshop.apphb.com/ a simple ASP.NET application using the following NuGet packages:

```
Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet
Dapper
MySql.Data
```

The application uses MySQL. I've activated the addon and labeled the instance using the same name written in my **Web.config**. (I'v also deplyoed my db to that instance).

NancyFx is configured in `system.webServer/handler` and not in `system.web/httpHandlers`.

I've also set `system.web/customErrors` to `Off`.

What am I missing for get `500 - Internal Server Error`?

The interesting thing is that static files are served correctly (http://domainshop.apphb.com/assets/style.css).

Regards,
Giacomo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are your views set with a build action of Content?
I have had this before where my view files are set to None and so are not deployed by AppHarbor.

Comment: No, my only view (views/search.sshtml) is set Build Action=None). This is the code of my module (http://pastebin.com/9qD2Ha1s). Can be of any help to solve the problem? I've also tried to deploy to a local IIS and it seems that IIS "doesn't pass the control" to NancyFx. Why?

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask It explains about how to mark my answer as being correct. This lets other users quickly see which answer will solve their similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I would guess that something (database access perhaps?) in your route is throwing an exception. Doesn't sound like Nancy is broken because you are able to access the static content

Comment: I've also tried running the local app with the remote db, so I think the db was deployed correctly. This is my web.config (http://pastebin.com/aFd3qadK); what else I should post to get more help?